# 2002 honda accord

Tags: honda, accord

when I drive my car the front right wheel sounds like it is flat then I hear a poping sound not all the time it comes and goes  I had new brake pads put on 3 days early  the brakes had went into the roter a little my car is a 2002 Honda accord

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like you have a bad wheel bearing as well as a bad CV Joint on that side of the vehicle. You won't know until someone takes a look at it though. If the CV Joint was going out, you'd hear it when driving slow and turn the car through a corner, usually in either direction. It will have a pop-pop-pop-pop continuously until you straighten the wheel out. The wheel bearing is just going to be a grind you'll most likely feel versus actually hearing (until it gets really bad). Both could be on the same side.